# Apache camel Logging and Debugging to file

Tags: logging, apache-camel

Im using camel route deployed in service mix.

```
from("file://E://Target//Customers")
.transacted()
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"FolderToJMS","Sending File to JMS Queue ${body}")
.to("jmstx:queue:transaction-handler");
```

This log message is getting printed in servicemix log.

If i need to log it into another log file how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of log method is logger name, where in your case it is "FolderToJMS". Just configure this logger and corresponding file appender under

```
SERVICEMIX_HOME/config/logback.xml
```

Please take look on this article for more details on how to configure logback file appender http://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/

**EDIT**

Sorry for confusing, default servicemix distribution use log4j instead of logback (I have missed it because of our custom branded servicemix version). Please add this code into SERVICEMIX_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg

```
# Custom file appender
log4j.appender.customFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.customFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.customFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n
log4j.appender.customFileAppender.file=${karaf.data}/log/mycustom.log
log4j.appender.customFileAppender.append=true
log4j.appender.customFileAppender.maxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.customFileAppender.maxBackupIndex=10

# Custom logger
log4j.logger.FolderToJMS=DEBUG,customFileAppender
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried creating a config folder under ServiceMix Home directory and Tried File Logger logback.xml with loggername FolderToJms and deployed my routes in servicemix. I couldnt find any files created. Am i missing anything in my process.??

Comment: Which version of servicemix are you using?

Comment: Apache Service Mix 5.4.0

Comment: Sorry for being newbie, Do i need to install anything for logback and include any dependencies?

Comment: thanks alot it worked. So if i have to create another such route specific log along with create log file, do i need to create one more such entry..?

Comment: Please take a look at this article which explain how appenders/loggers concept work https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html In addition, when you when you are happy with my answers please upvote.